# Is there a way to filter a dataset based on the number of decimal places?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset, but the only values that I want to run the analysis on have 4 decimal points. Is there a way to filter out all values with less than 4 d.p?

Please and thank you.

Comment: Provide example data, and expected output.

Comment: Maybe try: `x[ nchar(as.character(x)) >= 6 ]` convert to character and check the number of characters?

Comment: Example data: a column with a list of numbers with varying numbers of decimal places: 0.1235,0.1236,0.36975, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3654. but anything with less than 4 dp is not accurate enough, so I want to filter dataset to only have rows with 4 dp, i.e. : 0.1235,0.1236,0.36975, 0.3654.

Comment: Please edit your post with `dput(head(myData$myColumn, 10))`